# Styling TabItem when populated with ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, controltemplate, tabitem, itemssource

I'm using a WPF Tabcontrol populated with a collection using Itemssource.

```
<TabControl x:Name="_tabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding TabViewModelList}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding TabCaption}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding TabContent}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsDefault}"/>
                </Style>
                </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TabControl>
```

Now I want to set my TabItem-style in my App.xaml(or other resourcefile) like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border
             Name="Border"
             Background="LightBlue"
             BorderBrush="Black"
             BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
             CornerRadius="6,6,0,0" >
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               ContentSource="Header"
               Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

..but the ItemContainerStyle, of course overrides the controltemplate.

How do I combine these two so I can load my tabcontrol dynamically and still be able to style my TabItems the way I want to?

Answer (score 1):

Ok... Solved my own problem. Pretty obvious..

Named my template

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemTemplate">
```

Added a BasedOn property like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}">
```

But if I could combine them into one template please let me know...